# Sed converting underscore string to CamelCase fails on numbers

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace, scripting

I have an assigment to convert function names that are written like this: function_name() to camelCase. There are some restrictions:

- don't convert functions with uppercase character in them
- don't convert part of function with two underscores (two__underscores())

I thought of sed command that works fairly well, except it fails on single digit between underscores:

command:

```
sed -re '/[A-Z]+/!s/([0-9a-z])(_)([a-z0-9])/\1\u\3/g'
```

What it does:

- this_is_simple() -> thisIsSimple()
- this_is_2_simple() -> thisIs2_simple()
- this_is_22_simple() -> thisIs22Simple()

The problem is second example. Why it fails on single digit but not on number with more digits? I tried using [[:digit:]] and replacing ([0-9a-z]) with ([a-z0-9]|[[:digit:]]) . They work same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you very much. But I still have no idea, how to correct it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Because in the `22` case, the first `2` matches the last group from the previous match, and the next `2` matches the first group from the next match.  While in the single `2` case, the first match `this_is_2` is consumed, and the rest `_simple()` doesn't match with anything. Number is not special, ex. `this_is_a_simple` will fail also, and anything with one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through it manually and replace up until there is nothing more to replace.

```
sed -re '/[A-Z]+/!{ : again; /([0-9a-zA-Z])_([a-z0-9])/{ s//\1\u\2/; b again; }; }'
```

I have added `A-Z` in the first regex to handle cases like:

```
this_is_a_simple -> thisIsASimple
```

After the first match it becomes `thisIsA_simple`, so in the second loop we  want to match `A_simple`.

Maybe a better version would be:

```
sed -re '/[A-Z]+/!{ : again; /(.*[0-9a-z])_([a-z0-9])/{ s//\1\u\2/; b again; }; }'
```

Because regex is greedy, this will replace from the end, so `this_is_a_simple` at first becomes `this_is_aAimple`, then `this_isASimple`, then `thisIsASimple`.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! This solved my problem. :)  Do you have any suggestions for good sed tutorial? I haven't seen : again; loop before.